# Fake UINavigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm making an app in Swift and even though i'm using a navigation controller, there is a particular point where I want to present a view controller rather than make a segue and have the viewController added to the navigation stack.

This view controller i'm presenting is completely disconnected from the rest of the storyboard (it gets reused by a few screens).

To "fake" that it's part of the navigation controller stack, I wanted to drag and drop a navigation bar onto this orphaned view controller, and then manually add a back button. I want to handle my own back functionality and then use  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) to go back.

The problem is that this navigation bar doesn't have the same height or feel as the traditional one - the back button is way up high almost hitting the carrier/bars of service/4g/LTE area, and the title is touching the top of the screen. It's too high.

If I manually move it down, it's height doesn't occupy the whole area and there is this weird white strip.

Any ideas on how I can drag&drop my own navigation bar and get it to look like the ones typically done when you have a navigation controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you wrap your controller in a navigation controller, and present the nav controller modally:

```
    UINavigationController *modalNavcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:youController];
    [self presentViewController:mdalNavcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What a clever thing you suggested, thanks so much! It works! I had to actually hook up the back button but that's what I wanted to do all along. The back button appeared and everything. Thank you :)